# staticfiles.W004 Error, The directory '/app/static' in the STATICFILES_DIRS setting does not exist. Postgres tables are 0,

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, migration

django project deployment on heroku was successful
https://ddesigner.herokuapp.com/
"heroku run python collectstatic" fails with following error

> ?: (staticfiles.W004) The directory '/app/static' in the STATICFILES_DIRS setting does not exist.
> 1395 static files copied to '/app/staticfiles'.

"heroku run python makemigrations" also gives same error although new migrations are made

> ?: (staticfiles.W004) The directory '/app/static' in the STATICFILES_DIRS setting does not exist.

"heroku run python migrate" also gives same error and I see that migrations are applied (as displayed) but not actually. because postgres tables in heroku are zero.

Please help me to fix this issue.

I have tried removing

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
```

and also by changing
**STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')**
to
**STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')**

but the error is same.